# How to choose language using form and input

Tags: php, html, forms, input, submit

I'd like to create form with method="post" after clicking flag  language should be changed. How to send value after click ?

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <input name="btn_lang1" type="image" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>/public/images/strona/flag_pl.png" alt="Submit" value="pl"></input>
     <input name="btn_lang2" type="image" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>/public/images/strona/flag_gb.png" alt="Submit" value="en"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Use jquery / js to make a "onClick.submit();" ?

Comment: But without jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give the same name to your input "btn_lang" like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
     <input name="btn_lang" type="image" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>/public/images/strona/flag_pl.png" alt="Submit" value="pl"/>
     <input name="btn_lang" type="image" src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>/public/images/strona/flag_gb.png" alt="Submit" value="en"/>
</form>
```

And get in php :

```
$lang = $_POST['btn_lang'];
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your code , just check which button has been clicked and do something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_lng1'])){
?>
      this is where you should put your PL form
<?php
 }elseif(isset($_POST['btn_lng2'])){
?>
      this is where you should put your EN form

<?php
}
?>
```

> Important: This solution happens when the page is refreshed. If you
>   wants it to change the form dynamically , you have to use js